# Get SenderEmailAddress from mail item in compose mode

Tags: email, outlook, outlook-addin, mail-sender, multiple-accounts

I am retrieving, this mailItem in compose mode,  But when I check for the mailItem.SenderEmailAddress, it is NULL, but all other properties have values there (Ex:- body, body format, to, .... ). How I get the sender email FROM THE MAIL-ITEM IT-SELF?

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with Addin express v.7.7.4087

Here is the code :-

```
        Outlook.Inspector currentInspector = null;
        Outlook.MailItem mailItem = null;
        Outlook.Folder outboxFolder = null;
        Outlook.Recipients recipients = null;

        const string PR_SMTP_ADDRESS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E";

        currentInspector = Globals.ObjOutlook.ActiveInspector();

        if (currentInspector != null)
            {

            if (currentInspector.CurrentItem is Outlook.MailItem)
            {
                mailItem = currentInspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
                mailItem.Save();
                string sender = mailItem.SenderEmailAddress; //This is null 
            }
        }
```

**P.S**
I have to deal with multiple mail boxes. so, I can't get current users address using Namespace. It always return me the address of primary mail box user.

Please see following screen shot 
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Kushan Randima

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sending using multiple Exchange accounts? Use MailItem.SendUsingAccount, then read Account.SmtpAddress. If it is "", use Account.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress.

If MailItem.SendUsingAccount == null, you can assume the default account.

Comment: Awesome, this saved me. Thanks.

Comment: when I save the mail item in a self-created outlook folder and retreive it back, then 'SendUsingAccount' property is null. But it holds a value before save in outlook folder. So, I managed to add the value of "SendUsingAccount" as a user property before save it in OL folder and read it after getting it back. Is there any better solution for that?

Comment: How do you save the message to that folder?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [CurrentUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869341(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Namespace class to get the currently logged-on user as a Recipient object. The [Address](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867602(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Recipient class returns a string representing the e-mail address of the Recipient.

Comment: Thanks for the concern, Since I am dealing with multiple mail boxes, our solution will not work for me. Do you have any other suggestions please? I edited question too. Please see the changes. Thanks again

Comment: :If you are interested please commit for this : stackoverflow.com/documentation/outlook-addin/commit